# Each iteration takes longer spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a **Spark** application that mainly consists in a **loop** in where there is an **RDD** that is **transformed** and other RDDs are created to help the main RDD. On **each iteration**, the RDD **loses many elements** until the application reaches the last iteration step that the RDD has only one element. So, **each iteration should be faster** because there are fewer elements in the RDD.

**My problem is:**
On each iteration, the loop takes longer. I don't know exactly why. I tried to cache, but it was not useful.

Any advice will be appreciated.
Thanks

EDIT: I didn't paste the code because it is a bit hard

```
  def runAlgorithm(distanceMatrix: RDD[Distance], numPoints: Int): LinkageModel = {

  var matrix = distanceMatrix

  val sc = distanceMatrix.sparkContext
  val cont = sc.accumulator(numPoints)

  val linkageModel = new LinkageModel(scala.collection.mutable.Map[Long, Seq[(Int, Int)]]())

  object DistOrdering extends Ordering[Distance] {
    def compare(a: Distance, b: Distance) = a.getDist compare b.getDist
  }

  for (a <- 0 until (numPoints - numClusters)) {
    val start = System.nanoTime

    println("Buscando minimo:")
    val clustersRes = distanceStrategy match {
      case "min" =>
        matrix.collect().foreach(println(_))
        matrix.min()(DistOrdering)

    }
    println(s"Nuevo mínimo: $clustersRes")

    val punto1 = clustersRes.getIdW1
    val punto2 = clustersRes.getIdW2
    cont.add(1)
    val newIndex = cont.value.toLong

    println("Nuevo Cluster: " + newIndex + ":" + punto1 + "-" + punto2)

    if (a < (numPoints - numClusters -1)) {
      linkageModel.getClusters += newIndex -> Seq((punto1, punto2))

      matrix = matrix.filter(x => !(x.getIdW1 == punto1 && x.getIdW2 == punto2)).cache()

      matrix = distanceStrategy match {
        case "min" =>
          val rddPoints1 = matrix.filter(_.getIdW1 == punto1).cache()
          val rddPoints2 = matrix.filter(_.getIdW1 == punto2).cache()
          val rddUnionPoints = rddPoints1.union(rddPoints2)

          val newPoints = if (rddPoints1.count() < rddPoints2.count()) {
            val listPoints2 = rddPoints2.map(x => (x.getIdW2, x.getDist)).collectAsMap()
            rddPoints1.map(x => new Distance(newIndex.toInt, x.getIdW2, math.min(x.getDist, listPoints2(x.getIdW2))))
          } else {
            val listPoints1 = rddPoints1.map(x => (x.getIdW2, x.getDist)).collectAsMap()
            rddPoints2.map(x => new Distance(newIndex.toInt, x.getIdW2, math.min(x.getDist, listPoints1(x.getIdW2))))
          }

          val matrixSub = matrix.subtract(rddUnionPoints)

          matrix = matrixSub.union(newPoints)

          val matrixSub2 = matrixSub.filter(x => x.getIdW2 == punto1 || x.getIdW2 == punto2).cache()

          if (matrixSub2.count() > 0) {
            val matrixCartesian = matrixSub2.cartesian(matrixSub2)
              .filter(x => x._1.getIdW1 == x._2.getIdW1 && x._1.getIdW2 < x._2.getIdW2)

            val editedPoints = matrixCartesian.map(x => new Distance(x._1.getIdW1, newIndex.toInt, math.min(x._1.getDist, x._2.getDist)))

            matrix = matrix.subtract(matrixSub2).union(editedPoints)

          }
          matrix

      }
      matrix.cache()
    }

    val duration = (System.nanoTime - start) / 1e9d
    println(s"TIEMPO: $duration")

  }
  linkageModel
}
```

EDIT2: This is a snapshot of the UI. As you can see the task are increased on each iteration.
[Spark UI Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRa1y.png)

Comment: Given the lazy evaluation in Spark, the  `cartesianProduct` will be `M1xM2` in the first iteration, `(M1xM2)xM3` in the second, `((M1xM2)xM3)xM4)` in the 3rd... giving you an geometric progression as you add loops.